# Why following function cant be called with given argument list?

Tags: visual-studio, function, visual-c++

```
 void conver(double&, int&);
 private: System::Void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         a=1;
         if ((a==1)&&(b2==1))
         {if(cb1->Text=="Celsius")
             {
                 input=System::Convert::ToDouble(cel->Text);
                 if (cb2->Text=="Celsius")
                 {
                     choice=1;
                     conver(input,choice);
                 } 
                 if(cb2->Text=="Fahrenheit")    
             }   
         }
     }
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error: function "Project3::MyForm::conver" cannot be called with the given argument list.
>   argument types are: (double, int)

[image]

I don't understand what this means.
Can't we pass arguments by reference in Visual C++?

Comment: did you learn how to indent?

Comment: Where is `input` even defined? This code is incomplete, and therefore the question does not make any sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7701247/366904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an actual number - not a variable - by reference. You cannot pass in numbers by reference because numbers do not have addresses assigned in the registry (memory). You will have to use a variable.

You can do for example:

```
int myFirstNumber = 1;
int mySecondNumber = 1;

conver(myFirstNumber, mySecondNumber);
```

Comment: @Amar30657: Have you tried this solution? How did it work for you?

Comment: i wasnt seeking lik that itll probably work i guess but can u review my code again

Comment: @Amar30657, please create a new question for a different issue in the future. 

This drives the answerer to give much effort with no visible result. 

If the first answer helped you, please click the up-arrow to this answer.

Comment: u help i click if it was that so then why did stack ovrflow give edit option man come on help

Comment: @Amar30657: editing is for revising and **improving** posts.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong

```
conver(int&, int&);
```

needs integer reference variable

```
conver(1,1);
```

and you are passing constants

Try passing int variables

Answer (score 0):

`conver(1,1);`

You're passing numbers instead of variables.

Comment: Shouldn't it be:

void conver(double%, int%);

for CLI/C++?